# reading from text file and changing values c++

Tags: c++, file-io

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>   // For formatted input
#include <cctype>    // For the "is" character functions
#include <cstring>   // For strncpy, strncat and strlen functions
#include <cstdlib>   // For exit function
using namespace std;

int main() {
  ifstream fin;      // Declare and name the input file stream object
  ofstream fout;     // Declare and name the output file stream object
  char in_file[51];  // Filename for the input file
  char out_file[56]; // Filename for the output file
  char c;            // Current character in the file

  cout << "Enter the filename of the input file: ";
  cin >> setw(51) >> in_file; //setting max length of file name

  strncpy(out_file, in_file, 50);

  strncat(out_file, ".norm", 50 - strlen(out_file));

  fin.open(in_file);
  if(fin.fail()) {
    cout << "Cannot open " << in_file << " for reading.\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  fout.open(out_file);
  if(fout.fail()) {
    cout << "Cannot open " << out_file << " for writing.\n";
    exit(1);
  }

  while(fin.get(c))
    {
/* commented this out to see if a switch statement would output differently

    if (isupper(c))
    {
       c=tolower(c);
        putchar(c);
    }
    if (c=='/n')
    {
        fout<< endl << endl;
    }
    if (c=='/t')
    {
        for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
            fout<<" ";
    }


*/


switch (c)
    {
        case '\t' :                         // replace 'tab' by '8 chars'
            fout << "        ";
            break;
        case '\n' :                        //replace 1 newline with 2 
            fout<<"\n"<<"\n";
            break;
        default:                            // use default case to proccess all data and
            if (isupper (c)) {           // test upper/lower-case.
                char c2 = tolower (c);
            fout << c2;
            } else {
                fout << c;
            }
    }
    fin >> noskipws >> c;               // read the next character
}

fin.close();
fout.close();
  cout << in_file << " has been normalized into " << out_file << endl;
  return(0);
}
```

What I'm trying to do is have some input text file, append it with .norm and output it normalized with: 1.All tabs replaced with 8 spaces, 2.All upper case to lower case, 3.Double space the text. I thought my code would accomplish this, but I'm getting really weird outputs.

Here's an example of a text input:

```
DOE JOHN    56 45 65 72
DOE jane    42 86 58 69
doe tom 89 92 75 86
```

which then was output to:

```
dejh        64 57

o        ae4 65 9detm8 27 6
```

I have no idea what's going wrong and would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Suggestion 1: replace the `char` arrays with std:: strings for the file names. They needlessly complicate the simple task of reading user input and concatenating.

Comment: Sugestion 2: do not use `exit(1);` This is main. You can safely return. `exit` brings an axe down on the program killing it instantly and doing next to no clean-up of open resources.

Comment: And what looks like a killer: `while(fin.get(c))` reads in a character. But so does `fin >> noskipws >> c;`, so you suck a `char` into c at the end of the while loop, and promptly write over it with the `while(fin.get(c))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 while(fin.get(c))
```

reads a character at the beginning of every iteration of the while loop. But inside the while loop body, right at the end

```
fin >> noskipws >> c;
```

reads another character. This second character will be promptly written over by `while(fin.get(c))` and never be inspected.

This is shown by the OP's output: Every second character is transformed and written to the file.

Recommendation to OP: Learn to use your IDE's debugger. This was a trivial error that would have been immediately apparent if OP stepped through a few loop iterations.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into IDE debugging

Comment: Trust me, it's worth the time invested. Pays off within days, ramps the frustration level down dramatically when you can see what's going on, and is an absolutely vital skill in professional coding.